# Изменение содержимого темплейта директивы при смене передаваемого ей параметра

Tags: javascript, angularjs

- Нужно:
  При перемене значения option_sourse изменить `template` который использует директива `optionsSelector`. На данный момент значение `option_source` присваивается по умолчанию как `custom` и может быть изменино через селектор (drop down menu).
- Проблема:
  после инициализации в директиву `<options-sellector content-attr='{{option_source}}'></options-sellector>` передаётся правильное значение переменной(можно легко проверить), но `linker` не вызывается и соответственно используемый темплейт не меняется.
- Конечная цель:
  Заменить `#final_target` директивой которая при разных значениях "uib-dropdown" будет или `<input type="text">` или `<select>` с опциями из `$scope.queues` или `$scope.diverts`

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']).controller('DropdownCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.option_source = 'custom';

  $scope.status = {
    isopen: false
  };
  $scope.options = [{
    name: 'custom',
    disp: 'Custom Input'
  }, {
    name: 'queues',
    disp: 'Queues'
  }, {
    name: 'diverts',
    disp: 'Diverts'
  }]

  $scope.set_opt_source = function(type) {
    $scope.option_source = type;
  }

  $scope.toggled = function(open) {
    $log.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
  };

  $scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.status.isopen = !$scope.status.isopen;
  };

  $scope.queues = [{
    queue_id: "1",
    queue_title: "11"
  }, {
    queue_id: "2",
    queue_title: "12"
  }, {
    queue_id: "4",
    queue_title: "4"
  }, {
    queue_id: "6",
    queue_title: "dssdasfgdsfgsgf"
  }];
  $scope.divert_destinations = [

    {
      destination_id: "3",
      destination_name: "OOH Divert spain",
      destination_number: "08000157984"
    }, {
      destination_id: "4",
      destination_name: "Queue 1001",
      destination_number: "100672#1001"
    }, {
      destination_id: "15",
      destination_name: "Jacks Mobile OOH",
      destination_number: "+447733444314"
    }, {
      destination_id: "16",
      destination_name: "Chris mobile OOH",
      destination_number: "+447444668268"
    }
  ];

}).directive('optionsSellector', function($compile) {

  var testTemplate1 = '<h1>custom sellected</h1>';
  var testTemplate2 = '<h1>queues sellected</h1>';
  var testTemplate3 = '<h1>diverts sellected</h1>';

  var getTemplate = function(contentType) {

    var template = '';

    switch (contentType) {
      case 'custom':
        template = testTemplate1;
        break;
      case 'queues':
        template = testTemplate2;
        break;
      case 'diverts':
        template = testTemplate3;
        break;
    }

    return template;
  };
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log(attrs.contentAttr);
    element.html(getTemplate(attrs.contentAttr));
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  };
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    //transclude: true,
    //replace: true,
    link: linker,
    scope: {
      content: '='
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">


    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn" uib-dropdown>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " uib-dropdown-toggle>
          Source: <span class="caret"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="split-button">
          <li ng-repeat="option in options" ng-click="set_opt_source(option.name)">
            <a href="#">{{option.disp}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <input type="text" id="final_target" class="form-control" ng-model="option_source">

    </div>
    {{option_source}}
    <options-sellector content-attr='{{option_source}}'></options-sellector>



  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большие шаблоны лучше всего определять в html, а не в js через

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="name">...</script>
```

Либо в отдельных файлах через get запрос. Почитайте про директиву [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

Результат:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']).controller('DropdownCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.option_source = 'custom';
  $scope.status = {
    isopen: false
  };
  $scope.options = [{
    name: 'custom',
    disp: 'Custom Input'
  }, {
    name: 'queues',
    disp: 'Queues'
  }, {
    name: 'diverts',
    disp: 'Diverts'
  }]

  $scope.set_opt_source = function(type) {
    $scope.option_source = type;
  }

  $scope.toggled = function(open) {
    $log.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
  };

  $scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.status.isopen = !$scope.status.isopen;
  };

  $scope.queues = [{
    queue_id: "1",
    queue_title: "11"
  }, {
    queue_id: "2",
    queue_title: "12"
  }, {
    queue_id: "4",
    queue_title: "4"
  }, {
    queue_id: "6",
    queue_title: "dssdasfgdsfgsgf"
  }];
  divert_destinations = [

    {
      destination_id: "3",
      destination_name: "OOH Divert spain",
      destination_number: "08000157984"
    }, {
      destination_id: "4",
      destination_name: "Queue 1001",
      destination_number: "100672#1001"
    }, {
      destination_id: "15",
      destination_name: "Jacks Mobile OOH",
      destination_number: "+447733444314"
    }, {
      destination_id: "16",
      destination_name: "Chris mobile OOH",
      destination_number: "+447444668268"
    }
  ];
  $scope.watch('option', function(value) {
    if (!value) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(value);
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">

    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn" uib-dropdown>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " uib-dropdown-toggle>
          Source: <span class="caret"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="split-button">
          <li ng-repeat="option in options" ng-click="set_opt_source(option.name)">
            <a href="#">{{option.disp}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <input type="text" id="final_target" class="form-control" ng-model="option.name">

    </div>
    <div ng-include="option_source"></div>

    <!-- template "custom" -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="custom">
      <h1>custom sellected</h1>
    </script>

    <!-- template "queues" -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="queues">
      <h1>queues sellected</h1>
    </script>

    <!-- template "diverts" -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="diverts">
      <h1>diverts sellected</h1>
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/04x6hgox/1/).

---

**UPDATE**

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])

  .controller('DropdownCtrl', DropdownCtrl)
  .directive('optionsSellector', optionsSellector);

DropdownCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$log'];

function DropdownCtrl($scope, $log) {
  $scope.option_source = 'custom';

  $scope.status = {
    isopen: false
  };
  $scope.options = [{
    name: 'custom',
    disp: 'Custom Input'
  }, {
    name: 'queues',
    disp: 'Queues'
  }, {
    name: 'diverts',
    disp: 'Diverts'
  }]

  $scope.set_opt_source = function(type) {
    $scope.option_source = type;
  }

  $scope.toggled = function(open) {
    $log.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
  };

  $scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.status.isopen = !$scope.status.isopen;
  };
}

optionsSellector.$inject = ['$templateCache', '$compile'];

function optionsSellector($templateCache, $compile) {
  var suboptions = {
    queues: {
      1: 'queue_1',
      2: 'queue_2'
    },
    diverts: {
      3: 'OOH Divert spain',
      5: 'Queue 1001',
      15: 'Jacks Mobile OOH'
    }
  };
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
      $scope.$watch('option_source', function(value) {
        if (value === 'custom') {
          value = 'custom_control'
        } else {
          $scope.suboptions = suboptions[value];
          value = 'select_control'
        }

        $element.html($templateCache.get(value));
        $compile($element.contents())($scope);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">

    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn" uib-dropdown>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " uib-dropdown-toggle>
          Source: <span class="caret"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="split-button">
          <li ng-repeat="option in options" ng-click="set_opt_source(option.name)">
            <a href="#">{{option.disp}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group" data-options-sellector></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-include="option_source"></div>

    <!-- custom -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="custom">
      <h1>custom sellected</h1>
    </script>

    <!-- custom control -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="custom_control">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </script>

    <!-- other control -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="select_control">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="sel" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in suboptions">
        <option value="" selected="selected">select {{option_source}}...</option>
      </select>
    </script>


    <!-- queues -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="queues">
      <h1>queues sellected</h1>
    </script>

    <!-- diverts -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="diverts">
      <h1>diverts sellected</h1>
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/04x6hgox/6/).

Comment: Не совсем работает, но смысел понятен. Вопрос пока не закрываю, может кто ещё что посоветует

Comment: Не совсем подходит, картинка прыгает когда меняешг значение пример: http://plnkr.co/edit/eE6XWs?p=preview

Comment: @Dev: Уфф. Вы хотите в `<div class="form-control"></div>` вывести пояснение - имя выбранного шаблона? [Вот смотрите результат](http://plnkr.co/edit/jXGzu2IzDi7h4zerFFZ1?p=preview), я подправил ваш пример. Необходимо использовать `ng-bind="option_source"`, а не `ng-include`.

Comment: Нет не имя, там должны будут отображатся либо `<input>` если `custom` выбран либо создоваемые через `ng-repeat` `select` если выбраны queues или diverts

Comment: я потому и начал с директив что они могут полностью html переписать а не всраыить часть в див, сек пример накатаю ещё 1-н

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hNairB?p=preview

Comment: @Den: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо то что до надо

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в шаблон обе части и использовать `ng-if` для выбора на основе переданного значения.